# undefined method `params_require' - New into rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, blogs

I try to code a small blog in rails and when I tried to save a post through the website i get an Error. I can create a post with the console but thats not the goal.

this is my code for the create method:

```
  def create
@post = Post.new(post_params)

     if post.save
         redirect_to post.path
     else
         render "new"
  end


end

  def post_params
    params_require(:post).permit(:title, :content)
  end
```

would be nice if someone can help me. Thanks

Comment: it is `params.require`, not `params_require`

Answer (score 6):

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content)
end
```

Change `params_require` to `params.require`